# $this->upload->do_upload(); not working

Tags: file, codeigniter, file-upload

```
function do_upload(){//This is my controller//
    $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
    $config['overwrite'] = true; 
    //$config['max_size']   = '100';
    //$config['max_width']  = '1024';
    //$config['max_height']  = '768';
    $this->load->library('upload');
    $this->upload->initialize($config);
    $this->upload->do_upload();
    if (!$this->upload->do_upload()){//I also found out that this is the part that is not working
        echo "failed!";
    }
    else{
        $this->upload->data();
        echo "success!";
    }
}
```

"I have tried some tutorials to make this work but nothing seems to work for this one"

Comment: check you form enctype attribute is set or not. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_enctype.asp

Comment: <?php echo form_open_multipart((base_url()) . 'admin/do_upload');?>                                      
                                    <input type="file" name="userfile" size="20"/>                                       
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-sm pull-right">Upload</button>
                                    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
                                <?php echo form_close(); ?>

i checked that already, here is the code of my form

Comment: did you got failed message then try this print_r( $this->upload->display_errors()); also you can pass the file upload field name as  a parameter in do_upoad('userfile') method. example userfile is a form field name

Comment: this is the error message sir "The upload destination folder does not appear to be writable."

Comment: give full path here FCPATH for front controller path if you have folder outside the application the `FCPATH.'uploads/'` change it like this

Comment: give folder writable permission `sudo chmod -R 0777 <folder path>`. IF you have windows just give on right click on the folder make the permission change

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's may be file permission issue in "uploads" directory. Set proper writable permission to uploads folder.

Answer (score 0):

```
 'upload_path' => $image_path,
 'allowed_types' => "gif|jpg|png|jpeg",
 'overwrite' => TRUE,
 'max_size' => "2048000",
 'max_height' => "1000",
 'max_width' => "2000"
```

Try this.